# How to Automate Pyspark script in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, scheduled-tasks, pyspark, azure-hdinsight

Hope you are doing well.

I am new to Spark as well as Microsoft Azure. As per our project requirement we have developed a pyspark script though the jupyter notebook installed in our HDInsight cluster. Till date we ran the code from the jupyter itself but now we need to automate the script. I tried to use Azure Datafactory but could not find a way to run the pyspark script from there. Also tried to use oozie but could not figure out how to use it.

May you people please help me how I can automate/ schedule a pyspark script in azure.

Thanks,
Shamik.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory today doesn't have first class support for Spark. We are working to add that integration in future. Till that time, we have published a sample on Github that uses ADF Map Reduce Activity to submit a jar that invokes spark submit.

Please take a look here:
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/tree/master/Samples/Spark

Comment: Thank you Gaurav, I will try this approach. Except datafactory is there any way through which we can schedule a pyspark prohram in Azure HdInsight?

Comment: I tried with the example mentioned in the link and found that 'style': 'StartOfInterval' creates an exception stating there is a mismatch in the availability settings in output and pipeline. Once I removed that attribute from the pipeline json it got deployed successfully. Now I will check whether it is running or not.

Comment: The above mentioned link is not available now.